# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined but its fine when i just console log it reactjs

Tags: reactjs

im trying to mapping, its fine when i console the props like

```
console.log(this.props.companyScreening)
```

but when i try to map it, its return error

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

this is my function

```
 myFunc() {
   return this.props.companyScreening.map((company, index) => { 
       //some code
   }
```

this is my component. i call the function as i usually do. but this time i got error return

```
 class FirstHomepageComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sector: '',
        subsector: '',
        industries : [],
        companies : []
    }
}

myFunc() {
        return this.props.companyScreening.map((company, index) => {
            return (
            )
        }

}

render(){       
    return (
        <div className="my-class">
          {this.myFunc()}
        </div>

    )
}
```

}

the value of this.props.companyScreening is an array of object.

```
    [
                {
                    id:'1', 
                    companyName: 'PT. Lorem 1', 
                    companyCode: 'LI1',
                    industry: 'Finance', subIndustry: 'Bank', 
                    totalAsset : 999999, 
                    instruments: 12,
                    rating: [
                        {company: 'A', value: 'AAA+'},
                        {company: 'B', value: 'AA'},
                        {company: 'C', value: 'A'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id:'2', 
                    companyName: 'PT. Lorem 2', 
                    companyCode: 'LI2',
                    industry: 'Mining', subIndustry: 'Coal', 
                    totalAsset : 999999, 
                    instruments: 13,
                    rating: [
                        {company: 'A', value: 'AAA'},
                        {company: 'B', value: 'AA'},
                        {company: 'C', value: 'A'}
                    ]
                }
]
```

Comment: show the value of companyScreening atleast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Company Screening is undefined

You need to protect your app from undefined arrays.

change this

```
return this.props.companyScreening.map((company, index) => { 
  //some code
}
```

to this

```
return this.props.companyScreening ? this.props.companyScreening.map((company, index) => { 
  //some code
} : null;
```

If there is not data the function will return null. React will not render a component in that instance.

Comment: i already try it. also with if statement if doesnt work for my case